# Label doesn’t print integer value received from server in cocos2dx

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x, game-engine, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am getting json data from server like this -

```
if (response->isSucceed()) {
    log("Get success");
    std::vector<char>* buffer = response->getResponseData();
    std::string res;
    res.insert(res.begin(), buffer->begin(), buffer->end());
    log("res: %s", res.c_str());
    rapidjson::Document d;
    d.Parse<0>(res.c_str());
    if(d.IsObject()){

        log("true"); // print the value of obtaining hello
    }

     F = d["F"].GetString();
     W = d["W"].GetString();
     T = d["T"].GetString();
     Fp = d["Fp"].GetString();
     Wp = d["Wp"].GetString();
     Tp = d["Tp"].GetString();
```

}
Now i want to display that value of “F” using label…Value of F is integer number.

So i do this -

```
foodnumber = Label::createWithTTF(F, "fonts/A little sunshine.ttf",  40 );
foodnumber->setColor(Color3B(109,61,23));

foodnumber->setPosition( Vec2(foodtitle->getPositionX() + foodtitle-
>getContentSize().width/4  + origin.x, foodtitle->getPositionY() + origin.y) 
);

this->addChild( foodnumber);
```

It doesn’t print the value…

The value in the F is Number.

But when i log the value, it gets logged right, but it doesn’t get displayed on app as label.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try creating label with string like "Hello world" instead of F?

Comment: what is the position of `foodtitle` may be you're setting position of foodnumber out of screen.

Comment: Hi guys…

Finally got the label to display the value…What is happening is, when i put the label inside this braces

   `if (response->isSucceed()) {

     //parsing json here
    F = d["F"].GetString();
    //when i put label here, it displays valaue.

    }
     // when i put label here, it doesn't display value.`
it displays the value, and when i put it outside that, it doesn’t doesn’t display the value.

Although variable std::string F i have declared inside .h file.

The variable should be able to display the value anywhere in the .cpp file right?